# Hibernate Temporal.TIMESTAMP maps to mysql datetime without millis

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity with a field defined following way:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "some_datetime")
private java.util.Date someDateTime;
```

I would assume that Hibernate would create a table with corresponding column of type `DATETIME(3)` (for MySQL), however the table's column is just a `DATETIME`, so when I store a Date with milliseconds they are lost:

```
describe some_table;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ...           | ...          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| some_datetime | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ...           | ...          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I guess I need to add a `columnDefinition` parameter to the `@Column` annotation, but why it's not done automatically by Hibernate, as I explicitly told that I want to have a TIMESTAMP supported by the table.

I tried the above with:
 - **10.1.14** - MariaDB
 - **5.7.29** - MySQL

Hibernate version is **5.2.18.Final** with `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention: 5.2.18.Final, updated the question.

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: We're using `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect` dialect instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`.

As I see, the `Types.TIMESTAMP` type redefined here as `datetime(6)`

```java
public class MySQL57Dialect extends MySQL55Dialect {
  public MySQL57Dialect() {
    super();
    registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime(6)" );
    // ...
  }
}
```

But `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`  inherited the `Types.TIMESTAMP` declaration from the `MySQLDialect`  where it declared in the following way:

```java
public class MySQLDialect extends Dialect {
  public MySQLDialect() {
    // ..
    registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime" );
  }
}
```

And, by the way, this dialect is marked as deprecated:

```
/** A Dialect for MySQL 5 using InnoDB engine
 *  ...
 * @deprecated Use "hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb" environment variable or JVM system property instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class MySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Could you please just add that `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` transitively extends `MySQLDialect`, which [defines](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#L103) a TIMESTAMP column type as `datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not direct answer but if you in the beginning your developing process maybe it will be useful to use **LocalDateTime** instead of old **Date** object. In this case it is no need use **TemporalType.TIMESTAMP** anymore.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I inherited this entity and changing the type will lead to a big refactoring :(