# I used LocalDate my whole project, now it turns out i need LocalDateTime for a functionality, what to do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I was creating a blog which is almost finished. Everything worked ok with LocalDate until one point, when the admin creates a post a "creation date" and a "modified date" are added to that post which is saved in the MySQL database. Every time the user updates the post the "modified" date is changed.

One of the last functionalities I wanted to add was displaying the last 3 posts that where posted by the admin in a descending order. Now here is the problem: If the admin adds 3 post in the same day one after the other, then LocalDate is not able to sort them since it cannot distinguish between them since all have the same standard date, and the time is absent.

I tried modifying my JPA queries and every entity field and method to use LocalDateTime instead of LocalDate, but then this happens:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findAllByCreatedAtBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
    List<Post> findAllByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-09-01T12:27:19.341] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]
```

I read somewhere that 'between' does not work with LocalDateTime, now my whole project is broken.

I am confused and really annoyed I found out so late that LocalDate was the wrong choice in term of flexibility. Please help me understand what options do I have now in order to make that functionality work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The Post class:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long id;
   
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
   
    private LocalDateTime modifiedAt;

    @NotBlank(message = "Post Title is required")
    private String title;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private String image;

    @Column(length = 65535,columnDefinition="Text")
    @NotBlank(message = "Post Content is required")
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_TAG", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

For anyone struggling with the same issue, it is easier this time, instead of doing modifications that break the whole code to just sort the entities by ID. But next time pick a class that offers you more flexibility (like LocalDateTime) from the start since you never know what you need to implement down the line.

Comment: What's the code of the method `findAllByCreatedAtBetween`?

Comment: Why you can not sort your posts by record ID taken in mind that it's incremented for each new post.

Comment: @deHaar it is only a jpa query, i am using the between word along with 2 parameters.Thats it, no other code.

Comment: @StarnK that could be a way to sort indeed.My IDs are all unique and autoIncremented yes.But i would like to know if there is a way to use a date still.

Comment: What's the type of the corresponding database table column? Is it DATE or DATETIME or anything else? Could be of matter...

Comment: @deHaar it is of DATETIME.i tried adding ```@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")``` to my LocalDateTime fields and that changed the Column data type to TIMESTAMP but i receive the exact same exception.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` is not suitable for a `TIMESTAMP`, I think, it lacks a zone or offset which is needed for a non-ambiguous moment in time. But your error message obviously tells you that you have to refactor some other variables from `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTIme`...

Comment: Can you show the code of `Post`class ? I guess there is a `LocalDate` somewhere in it. Otherwise you have to find out where does that `LocalDate` in exception  message come from.

Comment: i have added the Post class @Benoit

Comment: What is the version of hibernate ?

Comment: @Benoit my version is 5.4.20.Final

Comment: Insure you use maven artifact [hibernate-java8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8/5.4.20.Final) to be compliant with java-8 new classes like LocalDateTime.

Comment: @Benoit i added that but i get the same issue it seems. I guess the easyest solution so i do not break my code is to just sort them by ID this time and use LocalDateTime for my next project.

Comment: @SternK if you post your solution as an answer i will give you rep

Comment: I think you have to replace `hibernate-core` with `hibernate-java8`, not simply adding it.

Comment: @helloApp One more question: what hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @Benoit i did, but same issue, still thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: @SternK this is what i use ```org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect=hibernate.dialect```

Comment: @deHaar JDBC explicitly defines a mapping for LocalDateTime and TIMESTAMP. Timestamp is a type without time zone information. You're thinking of a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that's right... I was thinking about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As was suggested in the comment you can sort your posts by record ID taken in mind that it's incremented for each new post.
2. Please note that you use deprecated [hibernate dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.java#L13). As it stated in the comment to this dialect:

> Use "hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb" environment variable or JVM system property instead.

Using this dialect can also lead to mapping problems with date/time data types. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815137/hibernate-temporal-timestamp-maps-to-mysql-datetime-without-millis).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij as ide, you can modify the method signature and then provide a default value while changing the signature.

Also you can replace all occurrences of the any statement by using shortcut key and replace all.

Comment: could you please give me an example of that?

Comment: ctrl + shift + r ==> will replace occurrence of a statement, with what you intend to put in all files. & ctrl + F6, will allow you to change method signature